# htacess URL rewriter not working on my hosting

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to change my URL `http://windllfiles.com/dlldata.php?name=All.dll` to `http://windllfiles.com/All.dll/` and `http://windllfiles.com/?character=B` to `http://windllfiles.com/character/B/`

I am trying to write my redirect URL for  `http://windllfiles.com/dlldata.php?name=All.dll` as

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule dlldata/name/(.*)/ dlldata.php?name=$1
RewriteRule dlldata/name/(.*) dlldata.php?name=$1
```

and for `http://windllfiles.com/?character=B` as

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /character/(.*)/ ?character=$1
RewriteRule /character/(.*) ?character=$1
```

but both are not working

Comment: `.` includes `/` in it. Use `[^/]+` for it not to be a forward slash. You can use `/?` to make the slash optional as well, then you only need 1 rewrite rule. Can you please update with complete .htaccess. `RewriteEngine on` shouldn't be present twice, and multiple rules may conflict

Comment: Seems also like question is written backwards, `http://windllfiles.com/character/B/` -> `http://windllfiles.com/?character=B` and `http://windllfiles.com/All.dll/` -> `http://windllfiles.com/dlldata.php?name=All.dll`, right?

Comment: Can you please explain more?

Comment: Which part? The `.` means any single character. A `/` meets that rule.

Comment: As per [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283057/mod-rewrite-questions-getting-migrated-to-sf) and [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283033/are-htaccess-questions-ever-on-topic-at-so) this question is not at all off-topic for SO so close vote is wrong. This has been discussed again and again and it has been settled already that most of the rewrite rules are created and maintained by developers of the web applications/frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^(All\.dll)/?$ dlldata.php?$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(character)/(B)/?$ ?$1=$2 [L]
```

first rule rewrites urls starting from All.dll to dlldata.php?$1 where $1 is first back reference value. 2nd rule applies for uris starting from character/B then rewrites to them to ?$1=$2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226572/discussion-between-gaurav-awasthi-and-ravindersingh13).